# Would a T test be appropriate for determining the significance of an algorithm's results?

Tags: probability, statistics, algorithms, computer-science, descriptive-statistics

Say you have an algorithm which should yield a higher score when given two similar images and a lower value when given two images that do not resemble each other. Two sets of tests are run, one where pairs of similar images are given and the other where pairs of different images are given. Each test set contains 10 tests on complex images. The algorithm yields a higher score, on average, for the images which resemble each other. Although this seems to confirm a hypothesis that the algorithm works, statistical significance needs to be calculated. Would a T test be appropriate for this? If so, should the normal distribution of results from both test sets first be proven?

Comment: Suppose you have 10 differences $X_i$ for similar and 10 differences $Y_i$ for dissimilar. If both X's and Y;s seem consistent with normal (roughly symmetrical, no outliers), then try 2-sample Welch t test. If both X's and Y's skewed in same direction with about the same variation, so one sample might be a shifted version of the other, then try two-sample nonparametric Wilcoxon rank sum test.

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion! Much appreciated

Comment: Just one quick question: Is the idea to make sure the continuous/combined results of X's and Y's are normal distributed, or that they are independently normally distributed?

Comment: Both X's and Y's should be consistent with normal dist'n (.e.g according to Shapiro-Wilk test), but for a 2-sample the Welch test they may not follow the _same_ normal distribution.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Comment continued:** Here are examples--perhaps helpful. You have said very
little about your data--maybe not.

***Two sample Welch t test in R:***  P-value near $0;$ highly significant difference between sample mean.
(Difficult to judge normality with such small samples. I generated these 'fake' samples from normal distributions, so I'm sure they're normal.)

```
set.seed(102)
x = rnorm(10, 100, 5)
y = rnorm(10, 120, 6)
stripchart(list(x,y), ylim=c(.5,2.5), pch="|")
```

[image]

```
t.test(x, y)  

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x and y
t = -5.5749, df = 15.849, p-value = 4.334e-05
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
   -20.854715  -9.357465
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 103.8186  118.9247
```

***Wilcoxon Signed Rank test in R:*** P-value near $0;$ highly significant difference between sample medians.

```
set.seed(121)
x = rgamma(10, 3, .1)
y = rgamma(10, 3, .1) + 20

median(x); median(y)
[1] 21.53694
[1] 54.64572

stripchart(list(x,y), ylim=c(.5,2.5), pch="|")
```

[image]

```
wilcox.test(x, y)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  x and y
W = 5, p-value = 0.0002057
alternative hypothesis: 
  true location shift is not equal to 0
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the suggestion